# Extract commit message using git rev-list

Tags: git

How to extract just the commit message using git rev-list command?

I tried git rev-list --format=%B --pretty=oneline -n 1 , but it prints the whole thing in 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 <commit>
```

would print out commit message and commit sha

```
$ git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit> | cat -
```

would print out commit message and no commit sha

Comment: There's no need to pipe the output to `cat`; if you want to disable the pager, just use `--no-pager`. But this is the right answer: `git log` and `git rev-list` are very nearly the same command, and if you want to suppress the commit ID you have to use the `git log` form of the command.