# git: how to get commit message (exactly) of commit?

Tags: git, commit-message

How can I extract the commit message (and only/exactly the commit message) of a commit?

`git show` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show doesn't seem to have an option for that

I could do `git cat-file -p <commit_hash>` and then search for the first \n\n and take everything after that until EOF, or I could do `git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit_hash>` but what is likely going to be forward compatible with future git versions? (of course, there's never a guarantee for that, but there's probably a 'best way' of doing this)

Comment: Have you looked at `git rev-list`? It's more or less the Plumbing equivalent of `git log`.

Comment: the linked answer also prints out the commit hash of the commit. is it 'safe' to just remove everything up until the first \n ?

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, I closed this as a dupe too quickly. Reopening.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420225/extract-commit-message-using-git-rev-list#comment66166309_39420243) from torek.

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid trying to parse a file directly; using a git command is likely to provide a backward compatible API even if the underlying data format changes.

I would use avoid `git log` but instead use [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show), which will let you examine a *particular* commit (instead of a range, which `git log` intends to do).  It does, in fact, [have an option for that](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_pretty_formats), allowing you to specify custom formatting options.

To show only the commit message subject and body, use the [`%B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt-embem) format and turn off patch display.

```
git show --pretty=format:"%B" --no-patch
```